# ViewBinding not working for layout included inside RecyclerView item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewbinding, android-include

This is my RecyclerView Item Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"><!--
    android:background="@color/home_item_bg"-->

    <include
        android:id="@+id/layoutSectionHeader"
        layout="@layout/section_header_rv_item_home"/>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMarketAndTerm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="NASDAQ - Medium Term" />

            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
                android:id="@+id/pieChart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/pie_chart_height" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is section_header_rv_item_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/llSectionHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"><!--
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_white_light_grey"-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvProductName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="@string/stock_exchange_barometer" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSeeAll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/see_all"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how'm accessing the views inside the included layout

```
inner class BarometerVH(private val rvBinding: RvItemHomeSeBarometerBinding) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(rvBinding.root) {
    fun bind(homeItem: HomeItem) {
        rvBinding.layoutSectionHeader.tvProductName.text = homeItem.title
    }
}
```

I got no compile time error, but getting this exception when I run the app

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Missing required view with ID: com.example.appname:id/layoutSectionHeader
```

Including a layout in Activity or Fragment works for me, but not working when used in Recycler View.

I tried multiple solutions given in this forum for similar exceptions, but none worked for a recycler view and not question regarding using <include inside recycler view.

Edit 1: I've added the overridden methods from the RecyclerView Adapter

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(
     parent: ViewGroup,
     viewType: Int
) = MarketCommentaryVH(RvItemHomeMarketCommentaryBinding.bind(parent))

override fun onBindViewHolder(
     holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
     position: Int
) {
    holder.bind(homeItemList[position])
}
```

Comment: Hello and please provide a bit more information. Show us (the relevant) parts of your RecyclerView Adapter, and anything related.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini, I added Adapter's overridden methods, please check. You can find the Viewholder in 3rd codeblock.

Comment: It's strange, but it appears ViewBinding is having troubles with the included layout, perhaps because it doesn't have a unique Id (since it's the same layout that you include over and over). Maybe for that bit, you may have to rely on the old findViewById. I haven't tested this, so I cannot give you at this time better advice.

Comment: I think you need to create a separate binding for included layout. So in bind() fun you should do something like `val layoutSectionHeaderBinding = LayoutSectionHeaderBinding.bind(rvBinding.root)` and than you could reference `tvProductName`

Comment: Thanks to @cactustictacs's answer, I realised that I was Directly binding the Layout without Inflating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `RecyclerView` works by creating and reusing a bunch of `ViewHolder`s, which hold a view layout to display the details of an item. You set these up in the `onCreateViewHolder` method, where you:

- inflate a layout for the item
- pass that inflated view to the `ViewHolder` constructor

You're not actually inflating the layout though, you're doing

```
RvItemHomeMarketCommentaryBinding.bind(parent)
```

instead of

```
RvItemHomeMarketCommentaryBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), parent, false)
```

(you need to pass in the `parent` while inflating a `ViewHolder`'s layout, so it can lay itself out with the correct dimensions etc)

---

The `bind` function on a `Binding` component takes an already inflated view hierarchy, and tries to find all the components with the IDs it knows about. So for example it tries to find `layoutSectionHeader` so it can assign `binding.layoutSectionHeader` to that view.

Trouble is, that doesn't exist in the `parent` layout you're passing in, because that's just the `RecyclerView`'s layout, it doesn't contain the stuff from the `ViewHolder` layout. So `bind` doesn't work - the views aren't there to bind to. You need to call `inflate` instead